# Numpy cannot access element, should I just un-nest array or is my array build wrong/inefficient?

Tags: python, numpy

I receive an out of bounds error when I try to access a specific element in my numpy array. I think it is related to the extra nested bracket.

My question is, what is the correct way to build this array, such that it doesn't have the extra nested bracket.

Or, if this is the correct way to build the array, then what is the best way to access the elements?

**This doesn't work:**

```
x = np.arange(0, 0.55, 0.05)
xy = np.array([[x], [np.ones(len(x))]])
print(xy)
print(xy[0,1])
```

Returns:

```
[[[0.   0.05 0.1  0.15 0.2  0.25 0.3  0.35 0.4  0.45 0.5 ]]

 [[1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.  ]]]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-dfc6fe66761b> in <module>
      2 xy = np.array([[x], [np.ones(len(x))]])
      3 print(xy)
----> 4 print(xy[0,1])

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

**This does work:**

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])
print(arr)
print(arr[1,1])
```

Returns:

```
 [[ 1  2  3  4  5]
     [ 6  7  8  9 10]]
    7
```

*Extra Context:* I am creating the second dimension in the array `xy` (the ones) as a place holder because I will be performing a simple calculation based on the x value. If there is a better way to do this using numpy that doesn't involved creating the place holder, I'd appreciate any tips. (I know that this is easy to do in a simple table using Pandas, or just as a simple Python list, but I am trying to learn about numpy.)

```
for ii in xy:
    # I want "y = x + 2" ... so do as: 
    # xy[1,ii] = xy[0,ii] + 2
    # but will also have an if condition, so not quite this simple
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...

Comment: The first one produces a (2,1,10) shaped array.  The second a (2,5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using extra square brackets?

```py
x = np.arange(0, 0.55, 0.05)
xy = np.array([x, np.ones(len(x))])    # removed extra brackets
print(xy)
print(xy[0,1])
```

Based on the second part of your question in the comments, I believe you need the following loop:

```py
for i in range(xy.shape[1]):
    print(xy[1, i])
```

Comment: I swear I tried that, tested a lot of different bracket configurations, but you are right, it works, thanks

Comment: Kindly consider accepting **iff** this answers your question

Comment: if I have `for ii in xy: print(ii[0])` do you happen to know how I can access the specific elements?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, `ii` in this loop will fetch each row; `ii[0]` already accesses particular element. What do you want to access?

Comment: `for ii in xy: print(ii[0])` returns `0.0 1.0`. I want to access the "1.0" so that I can calculate and replace the value (see "Extra Context" in the OP)

Comment: Updated my answer have a look!